# Iterating over two lists in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

So i have a function that gets a list of students from a web service and also query the localdb for all the students in there. the data is placed in two different list. So i want to check to see if a new student already exists in the localdb List. if it does, update it and it if doesn't then add it. i unable to get it working . I am trying to perform this using LINQ, but i can't seem to get it working right. My LINQ skills are amateurish at best.

```
        public async Task GetStudents()
    {
        String controllerName = "Students";

        List<Students> newStudentData = await RunGetAsync<Students>(controllerName);

        // get all the service types that already exists in the localStudent Db
        List<Students> currentStudentData = db.Studentss.ToList();

        foreach (Students existingStudents in currentStudentData)
        {
            foreach (Students newStudents in newStudentData)
            {
                IEnumerable<Students> selectStudents = from student in newStudentData  // check if Students exist in the database
                                                             where student.Id == existingStudents.Id
                                                             select student;

                if (selectStudents == null) // didn't find it, then add it
                {
                    db.Students.Add(newStudents);
                }
                if (selectStudents != null) // found it , then update the informations
                {
                    Students updatedStudents = new Students();
                    foreach (var field in selectStudents)
                    {
                        updatedStudents.FName = field.FName;
                        updatedStudents.LName = field.LName;
                        updatedStudents.ZipCode = field.ZipCode;
                        updatedStudents.AccessCode = field.AccessCode;
                    }
                    db.Entry(updatedStudents).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're looping more than you need :

```
foreach (Students newStudents in newStudentData)
{
     var student = currentStudentData.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == newStudents.Id);

     if(student == null)
     {
          //add
     }
     else
     {
         //update
     }
}
```

with `FirstOrDefault` you can find out if it exists and get a reference to it at the same time, if it does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Intersect and Except like below:

```
        //Find students that already exist to update
        var updateStudents = currentStudentData.Intersect(newStudentData);

        //Find new students to add
        var addStudents = newStudentData.Except(currentStudentData);
```

Comment: Out of box it's not gonna work if Student don't override default Equals behavior. Default Equals compare references not values.

Comment: true i'm not sure what the class looks like.